# How can I write Ember.js applications with HAML, SASS, and CoffeeScript?

Tags: ember.js, coffeescript, sass, haml

I don't want to be tied to any back-end framework and just want to write a full client-side Ember.js application that gets its data via various JSON APIs.

I haven't yet found a way to pre-compile writing a haml/sass/coffeescript application in a way that is satisfactory for my liking.

Comment: have you had a look at the ember-app-kit?   https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-app-kit

Comment: As for the haml checkout http://emblemjs.com/ Emblem is great!

Comment: @kiwiupover That looks great! Ember App Kit + Emblem might be the way to go. Thanks <3

Comment: One other advantage with the ember-app-kit is it is setup with the karmajs test runner and ember-testing which I have found helpful. http://adminjs.com/ is built on top of the ember-app-kit.

Comment: For the coffeescript part, take a look at [emberscript.com](http://emberscript.com)

Comment: Also you should take a look to http://yeoman.io/

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out [brunch.io](http://brunch.io) it has various skeletons to get started, is extensible via bower and takes care of everything that used to be a pain in the neck like minification etc.